# Class 'Swagger\Swagger' not found issue in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.3, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

I am pretty new to Swagger I just installed slampenny/Swaggervel and when I open the following url it throws error

Error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Class 'Swagger\Swagger' not found
```

Url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-docs
```

Answer (score 0):

In swagger-php 2.0+ there is no longer a Swagger class in the `\Swagger\` namespace, did you install the correct version?

Comment: I installed the correct documentation but still facing issue. Now changed the package.